# Linq Grouping & Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, distinct

Let's say I have the following records

```
Timestamp,Hash,Strength,Dev
1493898886.78,6483516d23526eed51504a59554c76b0f4c2f2a05973517ff451ce1abae06038,-68,273783
1493898886.78,6483516d23526eed51504a59554c76b0f4c2f2a05973517ff451ce1abae06038,-66,273783
1493898892.28,6483516d23526eed51504a59554c76b0f4c2f2a05973517ff451ce1abae06038,-59,273783
1493898893.0,f76dcc5bfefe5b0ab9a014149bc68f17bf4e12e60e285f4e66c7fcbbb725324e,-63,273783
1493898894.39,6d3c09d97816c0dda102b6f73205484a41a7e652af89e7fba7acff4f78879d89,-65,273783
1493898894.48,6d3c09d97816c0dda102b6f73205484a41a7e652af89e7fba7acff4f78879d89,-61,273783
1493898896.19,6483516d23526eed51504a59554c76b0f4c2f2a05973517ff451ce1abae06038,-63,273783
1493898900.19,6483516d23526eed51504a59554c76b0f4c2f2a05973517ff451ce1abae06038,-58,273783
```

If you notice the first record, the timestamp and Hash are duplicated, how can I with linq Select distinct records with highest Strength?

```
var dist = records
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.MACHash, o.Timestamp })
    .Select(y => y.Max(x => x.Strength))
    .ToList();
```

gets me only the strength, but i want the reduced list

Comment: The top two rows are completely identical.

Comment: -68, -66 strength...

Comment: Group by the hash and select max strength.

Comment: Show us what code you have tried so far, and we might be able to point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: var dist = records.GroupBy(o => new { o.MACHash, o.Timestamp }).Select(y => y.Max(x => x.Strength)).ToList(); gets me only the strength, I want the reduced list

Comment: Put that into the question, not a comment.

Comment: So, you've been a member of this site for 5 years and you have a sizeable enough rep to know how this works... how is it you're still putting code in comments and not providing us with an [MCVE] etc?  How is it possible you've missed that?

Comment: Your code example doesn't work because you specifically select only the strength and not the entire record. Tim's answer looks correct to me, you can see he selects the first record from a descending group.

Answer (score 1):

Following selects one record per timestamp + hash group, the one with highest strength:

```
var q = db.TableName
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Timestamp, x.Hash })
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Strength).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table name is A

```
from a in db.A
group a by new { TimeStamp = a.TimeStamp, Hash = a.Hash } into groupItem
select new { TimeStamp = groupItem.Key.TimeStamp, 
    Hash = groupItem.Key.Hash, Strength = groupItem.Max(x => x.Strength)}
```

You will get the max strength for each TimeStamp, Hash